# Drawing 5 paintings with 20 colors problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

We have 20 different colors. We want to draw 5 pictures (the order of the pictures is not important).

1.) We want to draw every picture with different colors, so that every color is on maximum one picture. How many different combinations do we have if every picture is drawn with exactly 3 colors.

1.)My try: $$\frac{\binom{20}{3}\cdot \binom{17}{3}\cdot \binom{14}{3}\cdot \binom{11}{3} \cdot \binom{8}{3}}{5!}$$

2.) Again we want to draw every picture with different colors, in how many ways can we draw, that we use all the colors and that on every picture there is at least one color.
2.) My try: I used Stirling numbers $S(20,5)$

3.)Let's say that we don't differentiate colors(we are colorblind) and we do the same as in 2.), how many combinations are there now?

3.) My try:

Natural number partitions: $V(20,5)$

Are the upper correct?

Comment: Are the pictures *distinct* ?

Comment: Yes looks correct to me

Comment: @trueblueanil It doesn't say if they are or not, it only says that the order is not important. My guess would be that they are not? But I don't know..

Comment: Another example of a poorly worded question ! Your guess may be correct, but if you **draw $5$ pictures** and color them, it implies distinct pictures